# Android: Draw a ProgressBar on canvas not working

Tags: android, canvas, progress-bar, draw, android-progressbar

Im trying to draw a ProgressBar on canvas. Im suspecting it doesn't draw itself because onAttachedToWindow is not being called...? If I try to draw a TextView it displays and draws it normally. I need to draw a ProgressBar on canvas, because there is no other way to display it as a decorator while the RecyclerView is loading https://yoda.entelect.co.za/view/9627/how-to-android-recyclerview-item-decorations

This activity is just a demonstration of how the ProgressBar should be drawn.

```
public class DrawingActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(0, 0, 500, 500);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(700, 700, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //Make a new view and lay it out at the desired Rect dimensions
    //        TextView view = new TextView(this);
    //        view.setText("This is a custom drawn textview");
    ProgressBar view = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);

    //Measure the view at the exact dimensions (otherwise the text won't center correctly)
    int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.width(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(rect.height(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

    //Lay the view out at the rect width and height
    view.layout(0, 0, rect.width(), rect.height());

    //Translate the Canvas into position and draw it
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top);
    view.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    //To make sure it works, set the bitmap to an ImageView
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    setContentView(imageView);

    // force the invalidation of the view
    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(view);
}
}
```

EDIT:

Adding the Layout decorator for RecyclerView:

```
public class LayoutItemDecorationTest extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private View view;
@LayoutRes
private int layoutRes;
private ItemPosition itemPosition;

public LayoutItemDecorationTest(@LayoutRes int layoutRes, ItemPosition position) {
    this.layoutRes = layoutRes;
    this.itemPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

    // view needs to be instantiated here, otherwise view animation doesn't work properly
    this.view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), layoutRes, null);

    // adapter items count
    int count = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    final int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.ALL) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, height);
    } else if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.FIRST) {
        if (position == 0) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, height);
        }
    } else if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.LAST) {
        if (position == count - 1) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, height);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Using onDrawOver to overlay any other existing decorators below
 */
@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    canvas.save();

    // adapter items count
    int count = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();

    // iterate through visible children
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

        if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.ALL) {
            drawView(canvas, this.view, parent, child);
        } else if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.FIRST) {
            if (position == 0) {
                drawView(canvas, this.view, parent, child);
            }
        } else if (itemPosition == ItemPosition.LAST) {
            if (position == count - 1) {
                drawView(canvas, this.view, parent, child);
            }
        }
    }
    canvas.restore();

    // animation stops if we don't invalidate on the next animation time step
    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(parent);
}

private void drawView(Canvas canvas, View view, View parent, View child) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

    // canvas translation coordinates
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;

    // canvas must be translated to the correct location, otherwise view will be drawn on 0,0
    canvas.translate(left, top);

    // view must be measure and layout
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.getSize(child.getMeasuredWidth()), MeasureSpec.getSize(child.getMeasuredHeight()));
    view.layout(0, 0, child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getMeasuredHeight());

    // draw the view on canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

Comment: simply add that `ProgressBar` to your `RecyclerView`s item view

Comment: I want to avoid doing that, because I want to have a clean item layout. Also this would mean i should be responsible for each item's state and that's what im trying to get away from.

Comment: True, but this still means im responsible for the item's state, where with a decorator i could simply remove it once the loading is finished. In your case I would have to signal the specific recycler view item (via payload) that the loading is finished. I'm not saying its not possible or to complicated, but i just see the decorator method as a much cleaner solution. However it might not be possible to implement it?

Comment: Yes i'm displaying a spinning wheel. On Lollipop the view gets invalidated if you call ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(view); but on Nougat it doesn't work and it doesn't even draw the ProgressBar.

Comment: The animation gets triggered when the view starts to be drawn on canvas. The decorator is added when the user reaches the bottom of the RecyclerView so the loader indicator is shown...are you genuinely asking me a question or...?

Comment: In this case the ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(view) method invalidates the view, thats why we see a smooth animation on Lollipop, but on Nougat I don't even see the first frame of ProgressBar. I will attach the code of the decorator also. See above...

Comment: @pskink I saw the pastebin code...Im aware that it can be done in that way, but I want to have a decoupled infinite RecyclerView, which means that the loading indicator should be a part of the RecyclerView and not its items...since we can add any item to it or any view holder. Think of it as a library where you could simply add a decorator to the view and not manipulate the ViewHolders.

Comment: so create a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` that adds that `ProgressBar` and use it as a base class for your adapters - so everything you would need is to change `... extends RecyclerView.Adapter<...` to `... extends MyAdapter<...`

Comment: @pskink Yeah maybe you're right...im getting hopeless with this decorator. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you want to use decorator then use it on `Canvas` level, do the draws directly (and not using any detached `ProgressBar`), just draw `Drawable`s like this: https://pastebin.com/QV9MsPjg

Comment: @pskink Cool I will try it...is it animated also?

Comment: try it, of course you will need to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar needs to call its startAnimation() method to start showing the spinner.

As it can be seen from ProgressBar source this method is called from onAttachedToWindow().

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    if (mIndeterminate) {
        startAnimation();
    }
 ...
}
```

To call this method ProgressBar should be added to the parent layout.

```
root.addView(progressBar)
```

Of course, ProgressBar may be inflated from xml, and you don't need to manually call the measure(...) and layout(...) methods anymore, as they will be called automatically when ProgressBar would be added to root layout.

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.progress, parent, false)
```